# ipython: disable copyright and help upon startup

Tags: ipython

when I start `ipython` from my terminal, I get following output:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 13 2014, 11:03:55) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 1.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]:
```

Is it possible to supress the copyright and help information? After having seen it a thousand times, I start to find it a little bit superfluous.

Ideally, I would like to see only the prompt `In [1]:` when I start `ipython`.

I am using `ipython 1.2.1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
ipython --no-banner
```

Note: I found this with `ipython --help`, which has a lot of other gems in it.